# Finding cache size by reverse engineering

Tags: c, performance, caching, memory, cpu-cache

I am trying to measure the size of L1 cache by reverse engineering. But I am getting somewhere wrong. When I compiled and run this code in my Linux terminal  I was getting a sudden jump of cycles at index 32 but even that was a jump of just 100 cycles. But my cache size is 64. I have no idea why this is going wrong? Do we need to clear the cache before running this code ? And also how to find the associativity of cache?

```
#include<stdio.h>

unsigned long long int measurecycle(char *baseaddress,int index){

unsigned long flags;
unsigned long long int start,end;
unsigned int cycles_low,cycles_high,cycles_low1,cycles_high1;

char variable;

  asm volatile (
      "CPUID\n\t"
      "RDTSC\n\t"
      "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
      "mov %%eax, %1\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low)::
      "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");

    variable = *(baseaddress+index);

  asm volatile(
     "RDTSCP\n\t"
     "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
     "mov %%eax, %1\n\t"
     "CPUID\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high1), "=r" (cycles_low1)::
     "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");


  start =(((unsigned long long)cycles_high << 32)  | cycles_low );
  end   =(((unsigned long long)cycles_high1 << 32) | cycles_low1);

  return end-start;
  }
    int main(){

    char array[128];
    char *baseaddress = &array[0];
    printf("Base Address \t| Cycles taken \n");
    int index;


   for (index = 0;index < 512;index++){
      printf("%p \t\t %d \t\t 
     %lld\n",baseaddress,index,measurecycle(baseaddress,index));
  }

}
```

Comment: The latency of RDTSCP and CPUID is certainly much higher than the L1 and L2 latency (and maybe even the L3)... The latency of the L1 cache is usually about 3 to 4 cycles. The one of the L2 on Skylake is 10-14 AFAIK. And the one of RDTSCP is certainly 30-100 cycles AFAIK. Your benchmark is flawed.

Comment: Could you please tell What am I supposed to change?

Comment: (a) Cache size cannot be 64; you need a unit, like 64 bits, 64 bytes, or 64 pages. (b) Your cache size is not 32 bytes or 64 bytes. L1 memory caches in general-purpose processors are much larger, like 32 KiB. A cache line might be 64 bytes. (c) More work needs to be put into the code to measure cache effects. A good compiler will completely remove `variable *(baseaddress+index);` from the code because it has no defined observable effect. Using `*((volatile char *) baseaddress) + index)` will prevent the compiler from removing it. You should examine the generated assembly to check.

Comment: (d) There is no reason to expect the tested address is not already in cache. When `main` is called, the program has just been loaded and started, and the stack was likely used by the start-up code, so the memory where `array` is put is likely in cache. You need to do something to ensure the memory used for the loads that probe cache is evicted from cache, such as forcing reads (using `volatile`) of a lot of other memory, so much other memory that, if it is in cache, the memory used for the tests cannot be.

Comment: Could u please tell why tested address would already be in the cache?